# Inject button into site (Chrome Extension content script)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to inject a button onto a page using Chrome's content scripts, but the button never appears, and I get no error in the console.

My `manifest.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Test",
  "default_locale": "en",
  "permissions": [
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": [
        "src/inject/inject.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

and my `inject.js` file:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var buttonOnSite = document.getElementById("buttonOnSite");
    var button = document.createElement("button");
    var text = document.createTextNode("test");
    button.appendChild(text);
    buttonOnSite.appendChild(button);
});
```

What I expect from the above code, is when I go to the site where a button with the id `buttonOnSite` exists, a new button, with the text `test` is created after it.

But nothing happens when I go to this site with the button! There is definitely a button with the id `buttonOnSite` (I've changed the ID for here, because it's a long ID).

I get no error message in the console, so what's wrong? It's probably something obvious, but I just can't see it. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the code you need:

```
var buttonOnSite = document.getElementById("buttonOnSite"),
    parent = buttonOnSite.parentElement,
    next = buttonOnSite.nextSibling,
    button = document.createElement("button"),
    text = document.createTextNode("test");

button.appendChild(text);
if (next) parent.insertBefore(button, next);
else parent.appendChild(button);
```

Comment: I still get nothing! There is no element after the `buttonOnSite`. So I want to create a new button after `buttonOnSite`.

Comment: It looks like the problem is with the `addEventListener`. I added some `console.log`'s within the eventlistener, and none of them ran. But they did run when I put them outside the eventlistener. Any ideas?

Comment: I edited the code, the listener may not call the function because chrome extensions default inject scripts after DOM Content loads. Try it now, but if this doesn't work maybe I don't get what you're trying to do. If you want you can link me the site and tell me what's the button and I'll try on it.

Answer (score 3):

By default, content scripts run after the DOM has loaded.  This means that you’re adding your event listener after the event has fired, so your listener never hears it.  Remove the first and last lines of your javascript.

Comment: That still doesn't work. Nothing happens! Please see my second comment on the other answer. Do you know of a solution?

Comment: Now I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null`. But the `console.log` messages never come up